# localStorage is not persistent across tabs in Chrome?

Tags: local-storage

localStorage is working perfectly on my Mac Chrome browser, but on my client's Mac Chrome browser each tab is like a different world with it's own localStorage. Even the http password authentication is not recognized across tabs. localStorage is empty on one tab, and on another tab there's content in localStorage. We verified this in a remote screen sharing session.

I'm trying to understand how his browser could be configured for this. I'm not seeing any unusual settings or extensions. He's not using Incognito mode. We checked his Safari, and there's no problem there. It's only his Chrome (even though it's the same version as mine) that is treating each tab as a separate window.

Note that Amazon.com does the same thing on his Chrome. He can sign in on one tab and he isn't signed in on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. He was using the Mac's dark mode, and somehow the Mac OS screws up Google Chrome. We were able to return Chrome to the expected behavior by unchecking dark mode.