# Local storage event listener not working for some users

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, microsoft-edge, event-listener

I have a React app that opens a new tab using window.open('myurl.com') to authenticate a user. In the new tab, authentication receives a response object and updates local storage.
In the original tab, there is a local storage event listener that triggers another action like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('storage', async (event) => {
        console.log(event.newValue);
        // do something with event.newValue here
    })
}, [])
```

For most users, this works perfectly. But for a handful of users, when I console log the new value in the original tab, it keeps saying null. For the users that it's working, they are primarily using Edge browser. For the users that it isn't working, we have tried Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and all in private mode as well. We have also tried updating the browsers to the latest version

Is there some sort of browser setting that could be blocking the event listener from being triggered for some users?

Comment: So for the users the value is `null` in all browsers? You can debug the code line by line to check the values set for those users to see if there's any situation the value will be set to `null`. You can check if [this situation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event#event_properties) exists: *The `key` attribute is `null` when the change is caused by the storage `clear()` method.* Besides, you can check if they enable cookies in browser settings for the site.

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. I made a mistake, when I console.log(localStorage.getItem(newKey)), the value returns null in the original browser . It's like localStorage is not being updated between browser tabs. Are you saying disabled cookies could be the cause of this? Unfortunately, I do not have access to debug line by line as the other users live in different states and it's working flawlessly for me

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can have a check. If possible, you can also check if there's any other error in console. If the app works for most users, the issue might be related with the user environment. You can also check if they have installed any browser extension. You can also tell them to clear all browser cache and data to try again.

Comment: So it turns out it isn't just the event handler that's causing the issue... local storage isn't persistent at all between tabs of the same origin. We've tried clearing all browser cache/data, they don't have any extensions installed at all, and there are no other console errors. I'm stumped. Could there be a system setting that is the issue?

Comment: It's so strange. Does local storage work well on other sites in that environment? Do they run the browser in InPrivate mode or kiosk mode or dark mode? I found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069178/localstorage-is-not-persistent-across-tabs-in-chrome) which says dark mode will cause such issue.